# PowerShell variable scope serial port

Tags: powershell, scripting, serial-port

Consider:

```
Function ABC {
    [Object] $Connection = ((New-Object -TypeName System.IO.Ports.SerialPort -ArgumentList COM1, 11200, None, 8, one)
    $Connection.open()
}
```

Now I want to use `$Connection` outside whenever I need. How can I access like

```
$Connection.write("`r")  # Calling from outside
$Connection.Readexisting("`r")  # Calling from outside
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return the `$connection` object from the function:

```
function New-COM1Connection
{
    $Connection = New-Object -TypeName System.IO.Ports.SerialPort -ArgumentList COM1, 11200, None, 8, One
    $Connection.Open()
    return $Connection
}
```

Now you can use it like:

```
$myConnection = New-COM1Connection
$myConnection.Write("`r")
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're running up against is scope. If you declare a variable within a function the variable only has the scope of that function and disappears once the function has run. What you will need to do is declare `$connection` outside of the function, pass it into the function, modify it there, and then still have access to the variable outside of the function.

Example:

```
$connection
function MyFunction
{
     param([Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][AllowNull()]$connection)
     # do work here
}
```

The other alternative is to declare the return value of a function as a variable

`$myConnection = MyFunction`

Then you can use `return` inside the function to return the variable.

Comment: many thanks, both answer works for me. though its long way to go now .